# What command-line options are available in Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) for modifying documents (Convert, Merge, etc.)?

Tags: command-line, adobe-acrobat

See title. I'd like to convert a bunch of XML files to PDF using Adobe Acrobat (9.0).

Currently, I'm opening each of these files with IE and then convert them manually using the Acrobat Plugin.

I'm curious if this can be achieved without loading each of the files by hand since the generation of the PDFs is a part of an otherwise automated process.

Comment: Depending on the specific type of XML, take a look at [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com) -- it has command line conversion.

Comment: Related over on StackOverflow: [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I asked explicitly NOT for the reader params.

Comment: @eckes "Related", not "duplicated". ;)  They actually share the same command-line options (good or bad) from what I've been able to gather.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there are no command line parameters for Acrobat for conversion.  The only command line parameters that exist are the same for Reader or for Acrobat to open a file or to print a file.  They are essentially undocumented and they are unsupported but you can see them [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_developer_faq.pdf#page=24).  You will have to look at other PDF applications for this functionality.

Another possibility is that if you have Acrobat installed and you can find an application that will open the XML files and has command line parameters for printing, then you can automate it through the XML application by printing to PDF from that application.  That's another avenue you might try to find.

Comment: +1 for your answer although it's not really satisfying. But sometimes, it's best to say *no*.

Comment: Yea, I know its a feature people have been requesting for years, but Adobe just ignores them like they do all their customers.

Answer (score 0):

not useful but the reason why adobe does not want to add cli to adobe standard / pro
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Distiller
Adobe Distiller

PDF Generator component of Adobe LiveCycle
https://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle.html#DigiSig

https://business.adobe.com/products/experience-manager/forms/features.html

Comment: Please fill in more information with your links and give context to other answers.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.